# App Inventor TinyDb data not properly stored

Tags: app-inventor, tinydb

so i have a mit app inventor  project for taking record on money expense based on certain category, i make two db using tinydb (dbHistory, dbTotal) in the add expense page, every time i add new expense, Instead of saving it to dbTotal data, it saves it to dbHistory why is that.[Add Expense Page Blok](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3L3GM.png)

so when i test it on my phone and display it in list view using getAllTags, the total which shoud be saved id dbTotal is displayed in dbHistory

here is the block on the home page
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3GGJO.png)

i expect it to be working normally where the total saved into dbTotal, and not saved in the dbHistory

i'v tried to do it one by one where i test only using the dbTotal only and its work same goes for the dbHistory but when the two combine and execute at the same time it give above problem

Comment: If you only dragged out two instances of tinydb to your project, they will be using the same database, even if you name them differently. You need to set different namespaces in order to use "two" databases.